# passing session state in clojure Ring

Tags: session, clojure, middleware, ring

I'm using a passwordless login system for my website, a user gets an e-mail and clicks the link to authenticate.  So far, so good.

How can I create or modify a ring middleware to retain and pass along the updated :session values?

```
(GET "/login" []
  ; gets a user's email and sends them a link to authenticate.
)

(GET "/login/:key&:email&:timestamp" [key email timestamp :as request]
  ; uses the timestamp, key, and email to verify the key
  ; if it all checks out, then set some session values
  ; e.g.
  (def updatedRequestMap 
   (assoc-in request [:session :supa-secret-smoken-token] "supercool secretval")))
```

How would I make sure that updatedRequestMap is passed along to future requests?

Thanks (=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `login` handler creates a ring response and assoc the newly updated session in that ring response.

```
    
;; put this in your ns declaration
;; (:require [ring.util.response :refer [response]])

    (GET "/login/:key&:email&:timestamp" [key email timestamp :as request]
         (let [old-session (:session request)
               new-session (assoc old-session
                                  :supa-secret-smoken-token 
                                  "supercool secretval")]
           (-> (response "You are now logged in")
               (assoc :session new-session))))
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to have a look at the
[ring-defaults](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults) library. It will add
some very useful middleware to your application, including support for sessions and
cookies as well as some useful security defaults. What it adds are standard ring
middleware components, so you should also check out the individual middleware
component documentation to see how it can help make writing your handlers easier